# Determine the most likely attempt to find a concealed item

Tags: probability

Given you are presented with 7 indistinguishable boxes, all empty but one containing a golden nugget. You are given the opportunity to open the boxes one by one. Once the box is opened, it remains opened. You will keep the nugget if you guessed correctly on which attempt you will find the nugget.

I approach this problem as follows:

The first attempt has a clear 1/7 chance. The second *requires* the first attempt to fail, *then* the second to succeed. Therefore it is 6/7 x 1/6 = 1/7. The rest follow suit and we get the uniform distribution:

| attempt # | chance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/7 |
| 2 | 1/7 |
| 3 | 1/7 |
| 4 | 1/7 |
| 5 | 1/7 |
| 6 | 1/7 |
| 7 | 1/7 |

However, this doesn't feel right. Could someone confirm/disprove my solution?

EDIT: My doubts regarding this approach and the question itself are inspired by the following 5 minute video: [Amazing Randi and the dowsing rod](https://youtu.be/xOsCnX-TKIY)

The video claims that by guesswork alone, you are most probably to locate the nugget by your 3rd or 4th attempt.

Comment: It's right. You're essentially choosing an order with which you're going to open the boxes. Without loss of generality, you choose the order $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$. So then the question is, can you predict in advance the box that contains the nugget? It should be clear that your probability of succeeding is $1/7$.

Comment: Thanks @BrianTung, I find your explanation easy to visualise. Would you be able to comment on why the 3rd or 4th attempt is claimed to be most successful?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct.  The situation you describe is equivalent to deciding *in advance* of choosing any of the boxes which of your choices will be successful.  It's obvious (via symmetry) that each choice is equally likely to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering and sequential opening of the boxes is a red herring. "Guess which attempt you will find the nugget" is exactly the same as "guess which box has the nugget in it", which obviously has a 1/7 chance of success with 7 indistinguishable boxes. Opening any of the other boxes you didn't pick is an irrelevant detail that doesn't matter in the slightest, it only matters if the nugget is in the box you picked.